# Unknown symbol returned when scraping web in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, decoding

I'm scraping the web using a node wrapper for the Bing API.
I print the text data from the results and I get some weird boxes with question marks inside of them. I've tried using escape and decodeURIComponent, but it's not getting rid of the symbols. What sort of encoding knowledge should I know to fix this?[image]

Comment: Probably UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @Patrick2607 so I need to encode it to UTF-8?

Comment: You can always try

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use regex pattern to replace anything not in the ascii char range (0-127).

```
x = x.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
```